# How to know the quantity of different items in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list of names (I, not Schindler, nor Arya), say:

```
names_list = ['Oscar', 'Itzhak', 'Amon', 'Ilyn', 'Melisandre', 'Cersei', 'Oscar', 'Cersei', 'who red this and didn't answer' ]
```

Also I have a list with some coordinates in my imaginary world, lets say:

```
coords = [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [2.9, 2.9, 3.3], [5.0, 1.0, 3.0]]
```

And I have a function, which I'll call tears_counter, so when I pass my list as my function param, it returns the quantity of different elements my list holds. So, in this case:

```
tears_counter(names_list)
>>> 7
```

and

```
tears_counter(coords)
>>> 3
```

Hope you have understood, *len()* isn't the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Would `print(len(set(names_list)))` help?

Comment: need to be generalized to differents types of data, not only strings, I used strings in the example for simplicity, but what if I need to be list the elements of my list? Set doesn't work anymore with lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will add our list's elements to the set and because of set stores unique elements, set's length will give us unique element count of our list.

But there is a problem. Set store values via hashing and because of lists are mutable and doesn't have hash so i need to convert it to a tuple (tuples are immutable!).

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def tuplify(value):
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return tuple(tuplify(x) for x in value)
    else:
        return value

def find_unique_count(data):
    data = tuplify(data)  # convert mutable objects to immutable objects.
    unique = set()
    for item in data:
        unique.add(item)
    return len(unique)
```

So, `tuplify` will convert multi nested lists to multi nested tuples (if any) and `find_unique_count` will add them to set. Finally set's length will give you our list's unique element count.

Examples and outputs:

```
coords = [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [2.9, 2.9, 3.3], [5.0, 1.0, 3.0]]
names_list = ['Oscar', 'Itzhak', 'Amon', 'Ilyn','Melisandre', 'Cersei', 'Oscar', 'Cersei']
data = [[[1.1], 2.2, 3.3], [[1.1], 2.2, 3], "this", [2, [[5]]], 141, 5, 3, "that"]

print(find_unique_count(coords))  # 3 , because 0th and 1th elements are same!
print(find_unique_count(names_list))  # 6
print(find_unique_count(data))  # 7
```

Comment: Dear Marceline, thanks for answering me, but what am trying to explain, in the second example is that, every element of the list, even if it is a list, is an unique element by itself, it, nor its subelemnts, so, in your example, [1.1, [2.2, 3.3]] is reapeated twice, but it counts as 1 element, then whe have "this", as the second element, [2,[[5]]] as the third one, 141, 5, 3 and finally "that" is the 6th element of your data. That's the expected output in this case: 6

Comment: I have edited my answer. I did not quite understood before but now my answer will give what you want.

Comment: Thanks Marceline, your aswer satisfied my expectations